# Which argument is causing a pipeline syntax error?

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

When I run the following pipeline in terminal (ubuntu)

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v 
   ximagesrc use-damage=0 ! 
   videoscale method=0 ! 
   video/x-raw, format=I420, framerate=30/1 ! 
   \ x264enc tune=zerolatency ! 
   mpegtsmux ! 
   \ hlssink playlist-root=http://192.168.0.11:8080 location=/home/gstreamer/hlstest/segment_%05d.ts target-duration=5 max-files=5
```

I get the error `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: syntax error`

What is the issue?

Comment: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not set property "use-damage" in element "ximagesrc0" to "0!"
```~$ gst-inspect-1.0 ximagesrc | grep use-damage
  use-damage          : Use XDamage (if XDamage extension enabled)```

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the pipe step by step and add "fakesink" at end.
So you can find which part is broken.

ex:

> gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc use-damage=0 ! videoscale method=0 ! fakesink